# Merging images in different channels with open cv

Tags: opencv

I am using opencv# for a project and trying to merge two images( one is an image with 3 channels and the other is a singe channel image). I tried using the methos Cv.ScaleAdd, but it wont merge two images with different channels. I need some help on this. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the result to be greyscale or colour?  The simplest way to add two images is declare a weighting for each one.  Say .4 for one and .6 for the other.  Then pixel by pixel multiply one image by .4, the other by .6, and add them to get a new pixel value.  If you want the final result to be greyscale start by converting the 3 channel image to greyscale, if you want it to be colour start by converting the greyscale to colour.  Converting a greyscale to colour won't actually colour it, it will just represent the grey with three channels.  You could code this yourself or I suspect the function call

```
cv::cvtColor(input,output,CV_GRAY2BGR);
or
cv::cvtColor(input,output,CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

followed by

```
cv::scaleAdd
```

would do the trick.